# SAS BI Content - Prompts

Tags: sas

Could somebody explain the difference between a "Standard Group" and a "Selection Group" with regard to the SAS Prompting Framework?

Standard groups - used to organise prompts into more usable prompt screens

Selection group - provides the user with the ability to choose the group of prompts to enter

Interested to know how & where these two groups are applied..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Standard Groups can contain any number and kind of prompts or groups (Standard, transparent or selection).  It's just a basic grouping.

Selection groups contain selection dependent groups that each have any number and kind of prompts.  This is where the top prompt can lead the user down different available prompt paths.  I think this is to help simplify the interface for the user to only show relevant prompts based on earlier selections.